# Draw a human body in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-core

I need to draw a human body in one of my iphone app . Can anybody help me in this

I am trying with "drawInContext"  but not getting any idea how to draw it

Below is the image how i wants in my app
[image: I want to draw like in this image]

And below is the code I am trying and it showing me just lines of human bodya

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context
{    
int lineWidth = ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) ? 2 : 10;

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);

//At this point we have a NSArray filled with at least 1 NSValue
//NSLog(@"Number of Segments %d", _jointSkeletonSegments.count);

for (NSValue *ourPointNSValue in _jointSkeletonSegments)
{

    struct SkeletonSegment ourPoint;

    [ourPointNSValue getValue:&ourPoint];

    //Draw the lines
    [self drawLineWithCGPoint:ourPoint.startPosition
             andSecondCGPoint:ourPoint.endPosition
                  withContext:context];

    //Draw the points
    [self drawPointWithCGPoint:ourPoint.startPosition withContext:context];
    [self drawPointWithCGPoint:ourPoint.endPosition withContext:context];
}
}

- (void)drawLineWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint andSecondCGPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint withContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
//Decide what color we want
UIColor *ourColor = [UIColor greenColor];

//Draw
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, ourColor.CGColor);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x + 0.5, startPoint.y + 0.5);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPoint.x + 0.5, endPoint.y + 0.5);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

- (void)drawPointWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point withContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
int pointSize = ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) ? 10 : 20;

CGContextSaveGState(context);

//Make the new rect in the center of the coordinate.
rect = CGRectMake(point.x - pointSize/2,
                  point.y - pointSize/2,
                  pointSize,
                  pointSize);

CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, rect);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect);

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Thanks,
Rafeeq

Comment: Why would you do that in code?

Comment: @trojanfoe I need to detect the motions of hand that i am doing right now but only thing is that i need to draw the body

Comment: dont draw this by code, you should use some vectorial, pdf or use svg > pixate-freestyle might help you for that

Comment: It's easy to use UIWebView with SVG file. You can interact with image via JS.

Answer (score 5):

Have you seen the application [Paint Code](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/) it's a drawing package that allows you to draw any image then it writes the objective C code to draw it !

[image: paint code app in action]

Comment: I was just going to recommend this, there are plugins to import SVG and PSD as well.

Comment: makes sense for buttons and dynamic things, for a shape... i'd go SVG

Comment: @VincentGuerci I agree with you. but there is option for image where i can drag the image of shape and get the points. do you think that this  can work for me ?

Comment: or at a push load in the exiting shape and trace it to get the vector.

Comment: Paint Code have just announced support for Swift code generation too. So any graphics you generate will be portable to Objective-C, Swift and Xamarin.iOS C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can use UIBezierPath  for drawing shapes. After creating a closed path, fill color.
You can use this link for reference

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html